# Avoiding map refreshes in print composer

Tags: qgis, export, pdf

I am trying to make a report with the QGIS composer. This report contains multiple maps. I don't have any trouble to make it, I just have to lock the maps with a right click to avoid them being refreshed while I change the layers in QGis.

However, when I decide to export the report as a pdf, the result is a pdf with copies of the same map. It looks like the "export as pdf" tool refreshed all maps.

How can I avoid that and have a pdf that matches my composer?

I am using Windows 7 and QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right clicking on a QGIS composer map item only locks its position, not the layers displayed within the map item. To lock the layers displayed, you must enable the "Lock layers for map item" check box in the map item properties panel:

[image: Lock layers for map item highlight]