# Creating print layout with 3 different maps of same area using QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing

I have a problem with the Qgis print composer: I want to create a print layout with 3 different statuses of the same geographical area, stylizing with 3 different fields. So far everything works but when I do the export to PDF or image format all 3 different maps are correct at the last style used. I can not figure out how to solve the problem.

(same problem here: [How to avoid map refreshes in print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39122/how-to-avoid-map-refreshes-in-print-composer) but this solution seems to me it does not work)

I tested on the following systems:

- Windows XP + Qgis 1.8 (postgres/postgis data)
- Windows 7 + Qgis 1.8 (shape data)
- Ubuntu 13.04 + 1.9 Qgis nightly b. (postgres/postgis data)

Comment: Is it the same layer that you are using in all 3 maps on the composer? You need to add the layer 3 times, and style each layer differently. Then set up the locked layers for each composer map

Comment: Yes, it's the same one layer. It is a pity that it is not possible without duplicating the layer, because in this way the whole project will be increasingly heavy to handle! Tnx James S

Comment: It does yes, but check out the new plugin that is called Layer Combinations on QGIS master. It makes managing layers in composer maps a lot easy to handle.

Comment: This video explains it well http://vimeo.com/70446444

Comment: Thank you very much for this info James S, with this plugin seems really simple.

Answer (score 2):

If your 3 stylings include different label styles for the same layer, then composer locks layers(as per your included link ie which ones are shown ) but style/labels/diagrams are printed or not accordingly to the main QGIS canvas. So the last style is used.

A solution is to duplicate your layer and affects a different vector style/label style for each copy. Create as many map items and for each map item, add the required layer.

Comment: Only the layer style changes, the labels remain the same. Tnx Hien